# MPMoviePlayerController - play fullscreen

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

Starting with this code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieLink];
```

The next thing I need to do is set the player's frame and add its view as a subview. But I want it to go immediately to fullscreen, and I want it to be on top of everything else. What is the best way to do that?

If I do something like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

The player does a weird resizing thing, then jumps to fullscreen. I know this is the last step:

```
[player setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
```

But where can I add the player's view so that I don't see any weird clipping or resizing? Do I use [UIScreen mainScreen] somehow? Or access the main window of the app?